# Hybrid-Hosting, how can I host one subdomain of existing site on second server?

Tags: web-hosting, amazon-aws

I have a domain like `www.example.com`, with a subdomain like `sub.example.com`. They are hosted by ex: Bluehost.

Which steps should I follow to just host `sub.example.com` on a second Server (AWS S3)?

Comment: You need to change the dns records for just that subdomain to the given AWS nameservers - contact bluehost about changing the dns record for a subdomain - they should be able to help

Comment: @sam thx a lot, make your comment an anwser so I can set it solved

Comment: i would do but the question is 'on hold' you'll need to edit it to make it as a less specific question changing it to something like ie. 'how to host just a subdomain on another server whilst leaving the rest of the site in place'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite simple not a big deal though.

You need to go to DNS entries in your first server where the main domain is hosted and add the second server's IP Address against the sub domain you wish to create here's an example.

Open main server (main domain) advanced DNS entries and add new entry.

> Name: `sub.example.com`
>   TTL: up to you enter of your own choice
>   Type: A
>   Address: second server IP address

Now go to your second server and create hosting for `sub.example.com`.

That's it.